# Why define the getter before the setter (coding convention)

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style, conventions

I appreciate this question is a little silly, so I apologise in advance if this is off topic or non constructive.

Why, in C# is it standard convention* to define properties with the getter before the setter? For properties with both you're almost always going to use the setter before the getter so it's in a valid state. Therefore, it seems a little backward to me that we define the getter first.

Also, the setter would typically have some validation logic, which the getter doesn't need. Would it not be tidier to have this logic ahead of the getter to make it clearer how the property should behave. For example:

```
public decimal Price
{
    get { return _price; }
    set
    {
        if(value < 0m)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        _price = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Price");
    }
}
```

The code in the setter is far more interesting than the getter, should it not take precedence and be defined first?

*I know there are no rules with these things, but practically every example ever, ever of properties defines the getter before the setter.

Comment: what about alphabetical order?

Comment: One had to be first. If it was the other way round then someone would probably ask why the setter was usually defined first.

Comment: Eclipse also suggests "first getters, then setters" and not "first setters then getters". http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-gettersetter.htm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because it is better to give than to receive.

On a more serious note, I'm guessing because whoever wrote the snippet (or whatever it is that auto-gens the property code in VS) subconsciously chose this order.

Then as the rest of us are just sheep to this pioneering shepherd, we followed without question.

Until you.

You question our once great shepherd, anarchy can only ensue. Commit your code and run for the hills.

Comment: I think it's time to move this question on philosophy.SE

Answer (score 12):

The getter is usually a lot shorter (usually one-line), so putting it in the beginning allows you to overview better, just like you will prefer this:

```
if (condition)
{
    // Short code
}
else
{
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
}
```

instead of this:

```
if (!condition)
{
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
    // Long code
}
else
{
    // Short code
}
```

And more than that - just because.

Comment: +1 for just because. Numerous times I see questions on SO such as "why write it like this?" or "why not do this?" and I think... "well, who cares?".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I care, hence the question

Comment: @RichK In that case you need to ask the person who wrote the snippet. It has no bearing on anything to do with C# and changes no behaviour, so why spend time dwelling on it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I find it interesting to know why particular coding conventions exist. There's obviously a reason as 99% of people define properties in the same way. I'd like to know why this convention won over the alternative. I don't care that it has no bearing on C#, nor does not using Hungarian notation, nor does all the other conventions that exist, yet we still follow them - do you never ask yourself why?

Comment: @RichK I ask why when it impacts readability, then I use my common sense when it doesn't. That said, regardless of the answer, if I don't like the convention I don't follow it. I'm not having a dig at you, but sometimes questions are so "well, just because", that you have to take a step back and chuckle at it all... For me there is a balance between understanding around the area and knowing what is relevant to be productive.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sorry, I know you weren't having a go :) I just get irked when people ask why I'm asking a question. I appreciate the question is entirely arbitrary!

Answer (score 1):

The order of the getter and setter are totally irrevelant, I think the reason for the convention is Visual Studio's property snippet which generated the properties in this way (getter before setter). So after using this snippet a couple of times this order have become an unwritten, unconsious practice for most coders (including myself). This of course doesn't explain why did VS designers implement the snippet this way. My opinion: they don't know it, and they don't care about it, or maybe because g comes earlier in the english alphabet than s. Anyway who on the world has so much time to care?

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing here is consistency. Whilst in your example, the setter is "more interesting", I don't think that this is necessarily the case the majority of the time. Indeed, one of the reasons that auto-properties are so useful is because of the frequency with which the get and set code simply read from/write to a private field with no other processing, in which case neither is "more interesting".

In your own projects, you are of course free to put them in any order that you like, and if you decide that setters should come first based on "importance" or some other reason, you're entirely free to do so. However given the widespread nature of the getter-before-setter convention, if you plan on sharing your code, it would make sense to follow convention for the sake of those that may need to read or change it in future.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with such a both interesting and adequate point of view of [@YoryeNathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991239/5113030).

I had been curious about the importance of the order, too, with the most frequently conclusion raised: Shouldn't be the data representation important in the code, and its flow in general? So we can get anything once and only when we set it previously. Sure thing, set is the first!", but... I do still see the following in my code:

```php
return [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,

    'c' => [
        'a' => 1,
        'd' => 3,
    ],
];
```

...and when I looked closer, I see that the first are the more simple or shorter data to also allow more of it appear on the screen, yet still be in an organized structure. Whether it be a configuration or data file like JSON/YAML or a source code member like a class, it feels that items like '{ enabled: true; }' should be higher and with more complex data moved down.

Considering that, "commonly" (based on subjective experience), `getters` are shorter, indeed, than `setters` in general classes or complex relatively non-standard DTOs even with additional validation and "seal" features, having `getters` at higher, and having those in member-scope groups, makes it more adequate I do believe. Not to mention that "get/set" should be in groups.

## Example

```php
<?php

use InvalidArgumentException;

class C1C2
{
    // Public Fields
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    public readonly ?int $a;

    // Protected Fields
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    protected readonly ?int $b;

    // Private Fields
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    private ?int $c1;

    private ?int $c2;

    // Constructor
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct(int $a, int $b)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    // Getters/Setters
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // C1
    // --------------------------------

    public function getC1(): int
    {
        return $this->c1;
    }

    public function setC1(int $value): void
    {
        if ($value <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        $this->c1 = $value;
    }

    // C2
    // --------------------------------

    public function getC2(): int
    {
        return $this->c2;
    }

    public function setC2(int $value): void
    {
        if ($value <= 0 || $value > 200) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        $this->c2 = $value;
    }
}

?>
```

## Related

[Which order to define getters and setters in?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/168153/219582)